# Docker build Input/Output error

Tags: docker, apt-get, docker-machine

I am quite new to docker, so I am sure i have made some silly mistake.

I am trying to use docker to set up an environment with my required libraries and dependencies installed for c++. However, I can't seem to get the VM built.

I am running on OSX Yosemite, and my installation process was as follows:

```
$ brew cask install virtualbox
$ brew install docker-machine
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

I have been able to successfully run a few examples to verify. However, I cannot run the following MWE Dockerfile:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-scm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libboost-dev
```

I get the following:

```
$ docker build .
docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 0 : FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-scm
 ---> a0b6d62d8b49
Step 1 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     libboost-dev
 ---> Running in d0dc09b47dac
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [172 kB]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease [134 kB]
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [123 kB]
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9038 kB]
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [3614 B]
Fetched 9534 kB in 8s (1183 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libasan0 libatomic1 libboost1.55-dev libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libtsan0 linux-libc-dev
Suggested packages:
  libboost-doc libboost1.55-doc libboost-atomic1.55-dev
  libboost-chrono1.55-dev libboost-context1.55-dev libboost-coroutine1.55-dev
  libboost-date-time1.55-dev libboost-exception1.55-dev
  libboost-filesystem1.55-dev libboost-graph1.55-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel1.55-dev libboost-iostreams1.55-dev
  libboost-locale1.55-dev libboost-log1.55-dev libboost-math1.55-dev
  libboost-mpi1.55-dev libboost-mpi-python1.55-dev
  libboost-program-options1.55-dev libboost-python1.55-dev
  libboost-random1.55-dev libboost-regex1.55-dev
  libboost-serialization1.55-dev libboost-signals1.55-dev
  libboost-system1.55-dev libboost-test1.55-dev libboost-thread1.55-dev
  libboost-timer1.55-dev libboost-wave1.55-dev libboost1.55-tools-dev
  libmpfrc++-dev libntl-dev glibc-doc libstdc++-4.8-doc
Recommended packages:
  manpages-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libasan0 libatomic1 libboost-dev libboost1.55-dev libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
  libgcc-4.8-dev libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libtsan0
  linux-libc-dev
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 132 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 [995 kB]
Get:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libasan0 amd64 4.8.4-1 [63.3 kB]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libatomic1 amd64 4.9.2-10 [8992 B]
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libgomp1 amd64 4.9.2-10 [37.8 kB]
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libitm1 amd64 4.9.2-10 [29.2 kB]
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libquadmath0 amd64 4.9.2-10 [129 kB]
Get:7 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libtsan0 amd64 4.9.2-10 [212 kB]
Get:8 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libgcc-4.8-dev amd64 4.8.4-1 [1689 kB]
Get:9 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.19-18 [237 kB]
Get:10 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libc6-dev amd64 2.19-18 [2003 kB]
Get:11 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libstdc++-4.8-dev amd64 4.8.4-1 [1053 kB]
Get:12 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libboost1.55-dev amd64 1.55.0+dfsg-3 [5818 kB]
Get:13 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libboost-dev amd64 1.55.0.2 [3368 B]
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: Input/output error
Fetched 12.3 MB in 6s (1797 kB/s)
dpkg: error: error opening configuration directory '/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d': Input/output error
E: Directory '/var/log/apt/' missing
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
E: Failed to write temporary StateFile /var/lib/apt/extended_states.tmp
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libboost-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Additionally, once this error occurs it seems that the daemon has crashed

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

> Error response from daemon: open
>   /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/repositories-aufs: no such file or directory

```
 $ docker-machine stop default
    $ docker-machine start default
    Starting VM...
    Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
    $ docker run hello-world 



Hello from Docker.
...
```

What could be causing these input/output errors?

Comment: What does `docker-machine --version` and `docker version` say? I tested your `Dockerfile` and it works well here with docker version 1.8.1 and docker-machine version 0.4.0. I am using VirtualBox 5.0.0 on OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: @h3nrik docker is 1.8.1, docker-machine is 0.4.0, and virtualbox is 5.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have fixed the issue (kind of), but it seems the underlying issue has not been resolved.

In answer to the question: the root cause seems to have been a conflict with Debian's package repository.

I changed the base image from `buildpacks:jessie-scm` to `buildpacks:trusty`. I was having a whole range of issues with even docker's base debian packages, having fails with commands such as:

```
docker run debian:jessie sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake"
```

or

```
docker run debian:wheezy sh -c "apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake"
```

Moving over to Ubuntu seems to fix the issue, so it looks like maybe it is a conflict with Debian's package repositories. I could try to fix it, but Ubuntu will work fine for my purposes (may even be preferable).

Answer (score 0):

The installation of Docker on OS X is now handled by the recently released [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#installation) tool.

You should use that toolbox as it will install and configure the Docker dependencies for you

Comment: I was under the impression that the docker toolbox was just the distribution of `docker`, `docker-machine`, and `docker-compose`. I am not using the older `boot2docker`.

Comment: Correction, `brew search docker` reveals that there is a `dockertoolbox`. I will install this and report back :)