# Docker Debian apt Error Reading from Server

Tags: docker, debian, apt-get

It would seem that apt-get is having issues connecting with the repository servers. I suppose it is likely compatibility issues, as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/690639/api-get-error-reading-from-server-under-docker), however the proposed solution of `apt-get clean` does not work for me. Also I am surprised, if this is the case, that there are not more people having my issue.

## MWE

> Dockerfile
>
> ```
> FROM debian:jessie
> RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
>     git
> ```

```
$ docker build .
docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 0 : FROM debian:jessie
---> 4a5e6db8c069
Step 1 : RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     git
---> Running in 43b93e93feab
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
... some omitted ...
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [3614 B]
Fetched 9552 kB in 7s (1346 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
... some omitted ...
0 upgraded, 26 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 64.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libgnutls-deb0-28 amd64 3.3.8-6+deb8u2 [694 kB]
... some omitted ...
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libnettle4 amd64 2.7.1-5 [176 kB]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libffi6 amd64 3.1-2+b2
  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 176.9.184.93 80]
... some omitted ...
Get:25 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main git amd64 1:2.1.4-2.1 [3624 kB]
Fetched 13.2 MB in 10s (1307 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.1-2+b2_amd64.deb  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 176.9.184.93 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     git' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Please note that I also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250489/docker-build-input-output-error) with a different issue. I believe it to be unrelated, but it may well actually be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [httpredir.debian.org](http://httpredir.debian.org/) mirror is "magic" in that it will load-balance and geo-ip you to transparent increase performance and availability. I would therefore immediately suspect it of causing your problem, or at least be the first thing to rule out.

I would check if you could:

- Still reproduce the problem; `httpredir.debian.org` will throw out "bad" mirrors from its internal lists so your issue may have been temporary.
- Reproduce the problem with a different, non-`httpredir.debian.org` mirror. Try something like `ftp.de.debian.org`. If it then works with this mirror, do please contact the `httpredir.debian.org` maintainer and report the issue to them. They are quite responsive and open to bug reports.

Comment: Yes you were right, I was able to reproduce the issue consistently last week, even over multiple days, however the above code works seamlessly now. I've been able to run the above MWE twice successfully. I suppose this highlights the unfortunate shortcomings and limitations of docker's level of reproducability

Answer (score 12):

For whoever is having an issue with this, this is my attempt to "fix" the issue by swapping out `httpredir` with a single working domain whenever the Dockerfile is being built:

```
FROM debian:je...

# Insert this line before "RUN apt-get update" to dynamically
# replace httpredir.debian.org with a single working domain
# in attempt to "prevent" the "Error reading from server" error.
RUN sed -i "s/httpredir.debian.org/`curl -s -D - http://httpredir.debian.org/demo/debian/ | awk '/^Link:/ { print $2 }' | sed -e 's@<http://\(.*\)/debian/>;@\1@g'`/" /etc/apt/sources.list

# Continue with your apt-get update...
RUN apt-get update...
```

What this command does is:

1. Curl the `http://httpredir.debian.org/demo/debian/` from the building machine to get the headers from debian demo page (`-s` is silent, don't output. `-D` is to dump headers)
2. Extract the headers, find the `Link` header fragment. This contains the best route as recommended by httpredir.
3. The last `sed -e ...` is to extract out the domain name of the link in step 2.
4. Then finally, the domain found in step 3 is being feed into the global sed command, and replace the domain `httpredir.debian.org` found in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

This is not a fix, but rather a simple hack to (greatly) reduce the chances of failed build. And... pardon me if it looks weird, as it's my virgin sed & piping attempt.

## Edit

On a side note, if the domain that it picks simply too slow or not responding as it should, you may want to do it manually by

1. Visit http://httpredir.debian.org/demo.html, and you should see a link there like `http://......./debian/`. For example, at the point of writing, I saw `http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/debian/`
2. Instead of the long `RUN sed -i....` command, use this instead:

   ```
   RUN sed -i "s/httpredir.debian.org/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/" /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

Comment: This is the only solution I have found for use in a Dockerfile (or other script that fails on every return code). The apt-get clean suggestion I have seen in a few places has not worked reliably.

Comment: Haha those cache clear and what not always fail me either. This is the only quick and dirty way for it to works in a near perfect manner. Although slow sometimes.

Comment: I have been consistently having this issue with rails builds in docker. the above solved it.

Answer (score 6):

I added `apt-get clean` to my dockerfile before the `apt-get update` line, it seems to have done the trick.

I guess I have no way of knowing whether or not it was the extra command or if it was luck that fixed my build, but I took the advice from https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-testsuite-dockerfiles/issues/19

Answer (score 1):

For those visiting with similar issues, using the `--no-cache` flag in the `docker build` may help. Similar issues (though not this exact one) can occur if the apt-get update is old and not being recalled sue to caching.

Comment: The --no-cache fixed this for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not enough reputation to comment on previous answers, so I will (confusingly) add a new answer:

- I don't think hardcoding a single mirror is really a viable solution, since as for example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923576/debian-httpredir-mirror-system-unreliable-unusable-in-docker), there's a reason debian implemented the whole httpredir thing -- mirrors go down or out of date.
- I've dealt with this issue a lot of times, and the logs always indicate that docker's actually running the apt-get command, which means --no-cache is unlikely to be fixing it -- it's just that if you rebuild, httpredir is likely to pick a different mirror, even if you don't change anything in your docker file, and the build will work.

Comment: Until they come out with a fix, I don't think there is a solution for this yet. My solution was not about hard coding a single source, but rather it helps you pick one that's up and running, and it sticks to it for that particular building session until it ends.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by adding `-o 'Acquire::Retries=3'` to the `apt-get install` command.

```sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -o 'Acquire::Retries=3' -y git
```

Seems that it automatically retries to acquire the package from another mirror.

[apt-get acquire documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.conf.5.en.html#THE_ACQUIRE_GROUP)

**EDIT:** After some investigation I found that my problem was related with the proxy server I was using. I'll leave the answer here anyway in case it helps anyone.