# Debian httpredir mirror system unreliable/unusable in Docker?

Tags: docker, debian, apt-get

#### Short Version

Debian's `httpredir.debian.org` mirror service causes my Docker builds to fail very frequently because apt-get can't download a package or connect to a server or things like that. Am I the only one having this problem? Is the problem mine, Debian's, or Docker's? Is there anything I can do about it?

#### Long Version

I have several Dockerfiles built on `debian:jessie`, and Debian by default uses the `httpredir.debian.org` service to find the best mirror when using apt-get, etc. Several months ago, httpredir was giving me continual grief when trying to build images. When run inside a Dockerfile, apt-get using httpredir would almost always mess up on a package or two, and the whole build would fail. The error usually looked like a mirror was outdated or corrupt in some way. I eventually stopped using httpredir in all my Dockerfiles by adding the following lines:

```
# don't use httpredir.debian.org mirror as it's very unreliable
RUN echo deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Today went back to trying `httpredir.debian.org` again because `ftp.us.debian.org` is out of date for a package I need, and sure enough it's failing on the Docker Hub:

```
Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/node-retry/node-retry_0.6.0-1_all.deb  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 128.31.0.66 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Here's the apt-get command I'm running in this case, though I've encountered it with many others:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  chrpath \
  libssl-dev \
  libxft-dev \
  libfreetype6 \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libfontconfig1 \
  libfontconfig1-dev \
  curl \
  bzip2 \
  nodejs \
  npm \
  git
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Debian apt Error Reading from Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304631/docker-debian-apt-error-reading-from-server)

Comment: @LionelChan You may be right. The accepted answer on that question is not helpful, but I'll have to give yours a try.

Comment: No bad feelings. I was just linking it back to the question as one of the answer below mentioned about it :)

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem today, when rebuilding a Dockerfile I had not build in a while.

Adding this line before the `apt-get install` seems to do the trick:

`RUN apt-get clean`

Got the idea here:

- https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/556
- https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/issues/40
- https://github.com/Silverlink/buildpack-deps/commit/be1f24eb136ba87b09b1dd09cc9a48707484b417

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: For me, the solution was to add both `apt-get update` and `apt-get clean`. I think this has to do with local caches being used which contain the apt-get update but might be some time old.

Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Overdue update: unfortunately, this didn't have any effect for me.

Answer (score 3):

From the discussion on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304631/docker-debian-apt-error-reading-from-server/37426929#37426929) question, and my experience dealing with this issue repeatedly over a number of months, `apt-get clean` seems to not in and of itself help, but the fact you're rebuilding (i.e. httpredir usually picks a different mirror) gets it to work. Indeed without exception manually triggering a rebuild or two has resulted in a successful build.

That is obviously not a viable solution, though. So, no, I don't have a solution, but I also don't have enough reputation to mark this as a duplicate.